# How to find memory leak in java using JProfiler?

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, jprofiler

How to find memory leak in java using JProfiler? I have been working in JProfiler for the past 1 week to find memory leak in a web application. I read some manuals and see some articles, it says see the memory usage in all objects and allocated objects views and using the allocation hot spot you can find the memory leak. I looked into it and found lot of memory used by char, string, bytes. Since i am a fresher i don't know how to figure this and solve the memory leak. Please help me over this ..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Here it is [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40119/how-to-find-a-java-memory-leak] is already discussed.

Answer (score 10):

See [this screen cast](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2017/03/finding-memory-leak-with-jprofiler.html) about finding memory leaks with JProfiler.

Comment: thanks for the video it is great, but my left side menu is different with yours, it is Live Memory, Heap Walker, CPU views, Threads etc. And when I was following the video and right clicked on the object could not find "Take heap snapshot for selection", rather the first option is "Show selection in Heap Walker". Do you know of any other video for profiling of Java Web Applications with newest version of JProfiler which is to date 8.0.5?

Comment: "Take heap snapshot for selection" and "Show selection in Heap Walker" are the same action.

Comment: Here is the new video link: http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2017/03/finding-memory-leak-with-jprofiler.html