# OutOfMemory exception even after increasing the memory (Maven)

Tags: java, maven

I get the following exception when I try to install Apache Stanbol as local instance:

```
ERROR] Java heap space -> [Help 1]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2786)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:94)
    at aQute.lib.osgi.EmbeddedResource.copy(EmbeddedResource.java:62)
    at aQute.lib.osgi.EmbeddedResource.collect(EmbeddedResource.java:51)
    at aQute.lib.osgi.EmbeddedResource.build(EmbeddedResource.java:33)
    at aQute.lib.osgi.EmbeddedResource.build(EmbeddedResource.java:71)
    at aQute.lib.osgi.Verifier.getBundleClassPath(Verifier.java:255)
    at aQute.lib.osgi.Verifier.<init>(Verifier.java:204)
    at aQute.lib.osgi.Builder.doVerify(Builder.java:434)
    at aQute.lib.osgi.Builder.build(Builder.java:104)
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.buildOSGiBundle(BundlePlugin.java:547)
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:347)
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:264)
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/OutOfMemoryError
```

I have increased the JVM memory using the following command, but still I'm getting the same error. My RAM is 4 GB.

> export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx3000m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"

How can I troubleshoot and fix this issue?

Thank you,

Jay

Comment: What's your Java version? You can't allocate more than 1.5Gb in 32bit system for Java. At the same time, I haven't seen any such huge application which needs more than 1Gb.

Comment: It appears your ?buggy? plugin requires much more than that.  Either you get more memory or log a bug to fix the plugin.  BTW 4 GB isn't that much these days, but a maven plugin should not need anywhere near that much.

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable to set is MAVEN_OPTS, for example MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m. The maxmem configuration in the pom only applies when you set the compiler plugin to fork javac into a new JVM. Otherwise the plugin runs inside the same VM as Maven and thus within the memory passed on the command line via the MAVEN_OPTS.

To set MAVEN_OPTS under Windows 7:

1. Right click on My Computer and select Properties
2. Click the Advanced System Settings link located in the left navigation of System Properties to display the Advanced System Properties
3. Go to the Advanced tab and click the Environment Variables button located at the bottom of the Advanced System Properties configuration window
4. Create a New user variable, set the Variable name to MAVEN_OPTS and set the Variable value to -Xmx1024m (or more)

Open a new command window and run mvn.

Answer (score 0):

This happens in an OSGI environment when you have a lot of resource filtering during the build process and not enough Heap Space allocated to Maven.

If you specify your resources and filters like this it should fix the problem...

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/filtered-resources</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.xml</include>
        </includes>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>

<filters>
    <filter>src/main/etc/org.yourcompany.yourproject.cfg</filter>
</filters>
```

> Note: The filter file is specified (file ending in .cfg)
>         Without this you will get the OutOfMemory error when trying to resolve resource tokens. Hence the Embedded Resource array copying.

Answer (score -1):

Increasing the memory is not the solution to OOM error. It can be temporary relief but not a permanent solution. You need to fix the code which is causing a Memory leak.

From the exception it seems there is some code which copying arrays and its doing it recursively causing the Heap Memory to overflow.

[How to find a Java Memory Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40119/how-to-find-a-java-memory-leak)