# k8s pod keeps OOMkilled often

Tags: kubernetes

So I gave my pod 12gb of memory to run my jenkins instance, it was "OOMkilled" every other day around the same time (4pm).

I increased the memory (16gb) hoping that it would fix this issues. It seemed to have fixed the issue of jenkins restarting every other days but I see the memory slowly increasing.

```
kubectl top pod
jenkins-pod    93m          15006Mi
```

I'm not sure what is taking up all the memory...any tips on how I can resolve this issue would be really appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java memory leak, only Jenkins running, Jenkins .war analysis shows nothing strange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24674912/java-memory-leak-only-jenkins-running-jenkins-war-analysis-shows-nothing-stra)

Comment: Please provide logs from the jenkins pods and explain in more details your workload.