# How to free heap space once in a day completely

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-management, garbage-collection, heap-memory

Is there any way in JVM (tomcat) where we can empty the heap space once in a day by writing any program or by using any settings.

Garbage Collector is a way, I want to know any alternate to GC.

Comment: Turn it off and back on again

Comment: You can free all heap space by killing the program. There is *no* other way and there never will be. Maybe you don't want to free all heap space?

Comment: Also, garbage collection is a fully automatic process that you should rarely need to think about.

Comment: It is not possible to turn off the server. Any Alternate to this

Comment: @ShahbazKhan Like I just said, it's impossible except by killing the program (which could include shutting down the entire machine) - and that's only because the heap *stops existing* if the program isn't running (other programs that are still running have their own heaps, but that one is gone). Why do you think you want to do it?

Comment: Some objects are occupying the heap space and not releasing, so the tomcat is going down frequently due to OutOfMemoryError, I am working on its solution but till that i need some program which takes care of server and Release objects implicitly.

Comment: So you're experiencing a memory leak and you'd better [find it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40119/581205). Releasing the whole heap is indeed equivalent to program restart and that's not the way to go.