# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space - Java 1.8 application running on Linux server

Tags: java, linux, shell

I have a simple Java 1.8 Web Application, that queries my database and displays the results with some other simple functions (insert/update).

From time to time I get this heap space error but I have no clue how to debug it. I've added some more memory but it does not help.

**Are there any tools or commands for linux shell that I could use to monitor what classes/methods consume the most memory?**

Comment: Use a profiler.  Visualvm is a good place to start.

Comment: How to make and view a heap dump: https://www.baeldung.com/java-heap-dump-capture

Comment: Requests for tool recommendations are off topic.  However the answers in the duplink include some leads.  More importantly, the answers explain how to debug the problem.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I can only acces the linux server with Putty, so I don't know how a visual/graphical tool could work?

Comment: Then hprof is your friend - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40215/53897

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen haha I just red that answer and I've gotta say that I lost it already at "Look for SITES BEGIN", absolutely no idea what that means :D

Comment: Isn't there a way of just getting the heap dump file and then investigate it with some graphical tool?