# Java Native Memory 'Other' section consumes a lot of memory

Tags: java, memory-leaks, profiler, async-profiler

**Prerequisites**

Application is run in docker-container with Java openjdk version "13.0.1" with these options:

`-Xmx6G -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=30 -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10 -XX:+AlwaysActAsServerClassMachine -XX:+UseContainerSupport -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath==/.../crush.hprof -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary -XX:+PrintNMTStatistics -Xlog:gc*:file=/var/log/.../log.gc.log:time::filecount=5,filesize=100000`

When I run `jcmd 1 VM.native_memory`, I get this:

```
Total: reserved=9081562KB, committed=1900002KB
-                 Java Heap (reserved=6291456KB, committed=896000KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=6291456KB, committed=896000KB) 
 
-                     Class (reserved=1221794KB, committed=197034KB)
                            (classes #34434)
                            (  instance classes #32536, array classes #1898)
                            (malloc=7330KB #121979) 
                            (mmap: reserved=1214464KB, committed=189704KB) 
                            (  Metadata:   )
                            (    reserved=165888KB, committed=165752KB)
                            (    used=161911KB)
                            (    free=3841KB)
                            (    waste=0KB =0.00%)
                            (  Class space:)
                            (    reserved=1048576KB, committed=23952KB)
                            (    used=21501KB)
                            (    free=2451KB)
                            (    waste=0KB =0.00%)
 
-                    Thread (reserved=456661KB, committed=50141KB)
                            (thread #442)
                            (stack: reserved=454236KB, committed=47716KB)
                            (malloc=1572KB #2654) 
                            (arena=853KB #882)
 
-                      Code (reserved=255027KB, committed=100419KB)
                            (malloc=7343KB #26005) 
                            (mmap: reserved=247684KB, committed=93076KB) 
 
-                        GC (reserved=316675KB, committed=116459KB)
                            (malloc=47311KB #70516) 
                            (mmap: reserved=269364KB, committed=69148KB) 
 
-                  Compiler (reserved=1429KB, committed=1429KB)
                            (malloc=1634KB #2498) 
                            (arena=18014398509481779KB #5)
 
-                  Internal (reserved=2998KB, committed=2998KB)
                            (malloc=2962KB #5480) 
                            (mmap: reserved=36KB, committed=36KB) 
 
-                     Other (reserved=446581KB, committed=446581KB)
                            (malloc=446581KB #368) 
 
-                    Symbol (reserved=36418KB, committed=36418KB)
                            (malloc=34460KB #906917) 
                            (arena=1958KB #1)
 
-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=18786KB, committed=18786KB)
                            (malloc=587KB #8291) 
                            (tracking overhead=18199KB)
 
-        Shared class space (reserved=11180KB, committed=11180KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=11180KB, committed=11180KB) 
 
-               Arena Chunk (reserved=19480KB, committed=19480KB)
                            (malloc=19480KB) 
 
-                   Logging (reserved=7KB, committed=7KB)
                            (malloc=7KB #271) 
 
-                 Arguments (reserved=17KB, committed=17KB)
                            (malloc=17KB #471) 
 
-                    Module (reserved=1909KB, committed=1909KB)
                            (malloc=1909KB #11057) 
 
-                 Safepoint (reserved=8KB, committed=8KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=8KB, committed=8KB) 
 
-           Synchronization (reserved=1136KB, committed=1136KB)
                            (malloc=1136KB #6628)
```

Here we can see that 'Other' section consumes **446581 KB** whereas total committed memory is **1900002 KB**.

So, 'Other' section takes 23% of all committed memory!

Also this memory is not freed when application is running.

Because of this I changed java flag `-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary` to `-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail` to check where memory is allocated and got this 2 strange blocks of memory:

```
[0x00007f8db4b32bae] Unsafe_AllocateMemory0+0x8e
[0x00007f8da416e7db]
                             (malloc=298470KB type=Other #286)

[0x00007f8db4b32bae] Unsafe_AllocateMemory0+0x8e
[0x00007f8d9b84bc90]
                             (malloc=148111KB type=Other #82)
```

**Analyze**

1. I tried to use *async-profiler* to check event **Unsafe_AllocateMemory0**.

I run *async-profiler* as agent like this:

```
java -agentpath:/async-profiler/build/libasyncProfiler.so=start,event=itimer,Unsafe_AllocateMemory0,file=/var/log/.../unsafe_allocate_memory.html
```

And got this flamegraph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbE5D.png

Also, I tried to profile events `malloc,mmap,mprotect`. `malloc` showed the same flamegraph as event `Unsafe_AllocateMemory0`, but flamegraphs for `mmap` and `mprotect` were empty.

I thought that problem can be related with C2 compiler and disabled it, but after restart nothing changed - the 'Other' section still occupied a lot of memory memory. Moreover, this application is long-living and I'm not sure that disabling C2 can be a good idea.

2. I tried to use *jeprof* to check which part of code executes `os.malloc`

I run java application like this:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libjemalloc.so MALLOC_CONF=prof:true,lg_prof_interval:30,lg_prof_sample:17 exec java -jar /srv/app/myapp.jar
```

After 10+ minutes I used *jeprof* and got this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/45adD.gif

And again there are 2 blocks of memory which occupied many native memory.

**Result**

I cannot find the place, which allocates so much memory.

Maybe someone can recommend how to spot the root cause of this problem? And what steps do I need to take to avoid this problem?

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks to [apangin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3448419/apangin) I have finally found the place, where so much memory is occupied!

It's related to *Redisson*/*Lettuce*, which are using Netty under the hood: [flamegraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UV48V.jpg)

I used experimental [native mode](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/discussions/491) and run java:

```
java -agentpath:/async-profiler/build/libasyncProfiler.so=start,event=nativemem,file=/var/log/.../profile.jfr -jar /srv/app/myapp.jar
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40119/how-to-find-a-java-memory-leak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your async-profilers arguments seem wrong.
Change `event=itimer,Unsafe_AllocateMemory0` to `event=Unsafe_AllocateMemory0`

async-profiler also has an experimental `nativemem` mode specifically for finding native memory leaks. See https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/discussions/491 for the details.

`Other` section in NMT typically includes off-heap memory allocated with `Unsafe.allocateMemory`, in particular, Direct ByteBuffers.

Comment: hm...I have never heard about `nativemem` mode. I'll try to use it and write update!
Thanks for the advice!

As for `event=itimer,Unsafe_AllocateMemory0`, I used `itimer` as java application resides in a docker container and this option is pointed out in the documentation.

Comment: `itimer` and native function profiling are completely different modes, they cannot be mixed.

Comment: thank you so much for the help!

I wrote update on the initial question.

So, now only need to find why Redisson/Lettuce use so much memory :)